# Required click for called Function

Tags: javascript, rotation

I had a previous question regarding this, but another problem has arisen. I want to rotate an element clockwise 22' and then back to the 0' initial state on click. The first function works out fine, but the second function which is called 3 seconds later, does not trigger unless re-clicked.

```
var rotated = false;

function clicked() {
    document.getElementById('box').onclick = function() {
        var div = document.getElementById('box'),
        deg = rotated ? 0 : 22;

        div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
        div.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
        div.style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
        div.style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
        div.style.transform       = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
    }
    setInterval(res, 3000);
    function res() {
        document.getElementById('box').onclick = function() {
            var div = document.getElementById('box'),
            deg = rotated ? 0 : 0;

            div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
            div.style.mozTransform    = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
            div.style.msTransform     = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
            div.style.oTransform      = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
            div.style.transform       = 'rotate('+deg+'deg)'; 
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the html and css too or replicate the current #box div with the css and js in jsfiddle?

Comment: Because you're adding a click handler inside `res()` instead of just setting styles

Comment: What is the appropriate handler in this situation? Edit: I found .style works

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the handler from `res()`:

```js
var rotated = false;

function clicked() {
  document.getElementById('box').onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('box'),
      deg = rotated ? 0 : 22;

    div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  }
  setInterval(res, 3000);

  function res() {
    // document.getElementById('box').onclick = function() {
      var div = document.getElementById('box'),
        deg = rotated ? 0 : 0;

      div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
      div.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
      div.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
      div.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
      div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    //}
  }
}
clicked();
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Depending on your needs you could also do something simplified, for instance:

```js
document.getElementById('box').onclick = function() {
  clicked(this, 22); // this is the element clicked
  setInterval(clicked, 3000, this, 0);
}

function clicked(div, deg) {
    div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
    div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
}
```

```css
#box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```